# Modified RPi.GPIO package causes "'module' object has no attribute 'RPI_REVISION'" in camera.py?

Tags: camera, rpi.gpio, i2c

My picamera was working fine this morning. i.e the following code was working fine

```
import time
import picamera
frames="/home/pi/Desktop/picamTEST.raw"

camera=picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (256,256)
camera.framerate = 30
time.sleep(2)
camera.shutter_speed=camera.exposure_speed
camera.exposure_mode='off'
g = camera.awb_gains
camera.awb_mode = 'off'
camera.awb_gains = g
camera.shutter_speed = 30000
camera.awb_gains = (1,1)

camera.start_preview()
camera.start_recording(frames,format='rgb')
camera.wait_recording(13)
camera.stop_recording()
camera.stop_preview()
```

Then I followed the installation instructions at the [following site](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/downloads/) to try and get matplotlib functionality in pi. However, now I get the following error message when I try to run the above code (error occurs on `camera=picamera.PiCamera()`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/PicamCharacterization/plotly-streaming/PicamCharacterization.py", line 29, in <module>
    camera=picamera.PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 445, in __init__
    }[(GPIO.RPI_REVISION, camera_num)]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RPI_REVISION'
```

I am a novice so, in addition to fixing my issue, a hand on how I should go about debugging something like this in the future would be appreciated.

I have changed all the files the links posted told me to change back to the way they were. Did the new RPi.GPIO-0.3 library I installed via the link's instructions deprecate the old GPIO library camera.py was using?

Where exception is thrown in camera.py:

```
def __init__(
        self, camera_num=0, stereo_mode='none', stereo_decimate=False,
        resolution=None, framerate=None, sensor_mode=0, led_pin=None):
    bcm_host.bcm_host_init()
    mimetypes.add_type('application/h264',  '.h264',  False)
    mimetypes.add_type('application/mjpeg', '.mjpg',  False)
    mimetypes.add_type('application/mjpeg', '.mjpeg', False)
    self._used_led = False
    if GPIO and led_pin is None:
        try:
            led_pin = {
                (0, 0): 2,  # compute module (default for cam 0)
                (0, 1): 30, # compute module (default for cam 1)
                (1, 0): 5,  # Pi 1 model B rev 1
                (2, 0): 5,  # Pi 1 model B rev 2 or model A
                (3, 0): 32, # Pi 1 model B+ or Pi 2 model B
                }[(GPIO.RPI_REVISION, camera_num)]
        except KeyError:
            raise PiCameraError(
                    'Unable to determine default GPIO LED pin for RPi '
                    'revision %d and camera num %d' % (
                        GPIO.RPI_REVISION, camera_num))
```

Comment: I'm afraid the RPi.GPIO library they're distributing at that site is *very* out of date which is why it fails to work with picamera. You shouldn't have to jump through any hoops to get matplotlib working: just `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` should be enough (that won't be the latest version by a long shot, but it should be functional enough)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=19565), you should just go and delete the libraries modified.

The libraries were installed to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.` (You can tell as per [the instructions](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/downloads/)) cd to that folder and delete all the packages installed using `sudo rm -r folder-name-to-delete`

If you can tell that deleting all the packages here is not a problem then you could delete everything using: `sudo rm -r dist-packages` . Careful when doing this.

camera started working again immediately afterwards.

Comment: This seems like a very bad answer for people who might have *other*, unrelated packages installed in that directory.  Which would not be at all unusual.

Comment: Yup, like a noob I only realised afterwards that I had to re-install a couple of libraries to get another program I was writing working again. At that stage correcting my answer was far from my mind. Thanx for reminding me. Answer amended.